# How to make a zoom window when taped in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been looking for days how to make appear a small window in screen showing in zoom what is under the finger, so you can move the finger around viewing whats under it.

You can see this feature for example in scanner applications, when you are cutting the margins with precision.
Sorry there is no code , honestly i have been doing the home work but does not know how to start coding this. thanks. 
here is an example.
[screen shot from scanner app. the circle shows in zoomed view what is under the finger, who is in the rigt corner of the picture!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rosMU.jpg)